# How to determine which marker was pressed on the map

Tags: google-maps, plugins, flutter

I am unable to determine which marker was tapped by the user on Google maps. I've added onTap: _onMarkerTapped(MarkerId markerId) event where I try to open another page with a more detailed Google Map based on which marker user has tapped. When I add bunch of markers (as a Set of markers) to my Google map, I do use unique markerId and that's what I pass in as an argument to a private custom method _onMarkerTapped(). The issue is, inside thsi event I always ended up getting the last markerId i.e. the last marker which I added to the Set. Is there any way to get the current markerid which user has tapped?

add onTap event handler for every marker I added in a set of Markers

```
for (var campusData in Campuses.campusLocations) {
      campusDetails = json.decode(campusData);
      campus = Campus.fromJson(campusDetails);
      markerId = MarkerId(i.toString());
      mrkr = new Marker(
          markerId: markerId, // a string for marker unique id
          icon: BitmapDescriptor.fromAsset(
              'assets/wsu@2x.png'), // options for hues and custom imgs
          position:
              LatLng(campus.latitude, campus.longitude), // lat and long doubles
          onTap: () {
            _onMarkerTapped(markerId);
          });
      campusMarkers.add(mrkr);
      i++;
    }
    return GoogleMap(
      initialCameraPosition: cameraPosition,
      onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
      mapType: MapType.normal,
      markers: campusMarkers, 
      onTap: (lng) => _onMapTapped(lng),
    );

void _onMarkerTapped(MarkerId markerId) {
    final Marker tappedMarker = campusMarkers.elementAt(int.parse(markerId.value));
    if (tappedMarker != null) {

    }
    else{
      print("Tapped marker is NULL..");
    }
  }
```

Looking for ways to determine which marker was tapped by the user

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to these two line:

```dart
markerId = MarkerId(i.toString());

...

onTap: () {
  _onMarkerTapped(markerId);
}
```

You are not creating a unique`MarkerId` for each loop, you are just reassigning it, so the last one you assigned will always be used by `_onMarkerTapped(markerId)`. To fix this, use:

```dart
final markerId = MarkerId(i.toString());
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response Hugo though it still returns markerId.value of 9 irrespective which marker user clicks on. i.e. didn't make any difference.

Comment: I've seen you have a `i` variable, but you're using a foreach, not a regular for. Where did that `i` came from?

Comment: i is defined as a variable fo type int with an initial value of 0 ... it get incremented on each iteration...

Comment: Then I cannot see what's wrong here. Please edit your question with a larger cut of your code, perhaps the whole build method.

Comment: ok, @Hugo further updates.. I managed to get this working by following exact example code on [ https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/google_maps_flutter/example/lib/place_marker.dart ] .... the major shift was instead of *Set*, I started using *Map* ```Map<MarkerId, Marker> markers = <MarkerId, Marker>{};```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who come across this issue, please follow the code example at https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/google_maps_flutter/example/lib/place_marker.dart .. especially the _add() method and _onMarkerTapped() methods. PLEASE make sure to use a Map to declare your set of markers e.g. `Map<MarkerId, Marker> markers = <MarkerId, Marker>{};`